# Get VM IP addresses eth0 ... ethn with ESX commands

Tags: esx

I need get all IP addresses that a VM has it. I only can use ESX commands, no PowerCLI.

If I use, with or whithout grep:
*vim-cmd vmsvc/get.summary 1 | grep -i "ip"*

I only get the first vNIC IP address, I need all :-(.
If, it is possible...

Thanks to all !!

Answer (score 1):

So, finally I get the solution.

With the command:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/get.guest <vmid>
```

We will have many keys *ipAddress* with the values, that we will may parse with `grep` command.